# How to display VAT after price in magento

Tags: php, css, magento, web

Im struggling a bit here. Basically, out client want the prices on the listing and product page to exclude VAT which is fine. But they she wan't written after the price '+VAT (£0.00)'.

Obviously the £0.00 will be the exact amount of VAT that will be added onto the product. So if its £20, it will need to say:

£20.00 +VAT (£3.40)

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override price.phtml. Create copy of price.phtml to new_price.phml and call it from catalog.xml file for product listing page. Also enable System->Configuration->Tax->Price Display Settings->Display Product Prices In Catalog : Including and Excluding Tax

Then, in new_price.phtml do some changes as below:

```
<span class="price-excluding-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, false) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Vat:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php //echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false) ?>
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax - $_price, true, false) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax - $_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            </span>
```

Hope it will help!